# How do I prove that this finite sum evaluate to $1+\sqrt{2}$ for all values of n?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, riemann-sum

$$
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 
\sqrt{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{i}}} 
{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 
\sqrt{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{i}}} 
= 1 + \sqrt{2}
$$

When $n=2$, this is easy to verify. As $n \to \infty$, we can turn this into a Riemann sum that gives the same limit. But seems this is true for all $n \geq 2$. How can this be proved?

Comment: Notation: you only ever have to write `\displaystyle` once in `$\displaystyle <math> $`. Better yet, if you wrap your math in *double* dollar signs, you automatically get displayed math.

Comment: Thank you @SammyBlack. Fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the sum or value of following expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012442/find-the-sum-or-value-of-following-expression), [Value of $\frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}} }{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}
$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397863/value-of-frac-sqrt10-sqrt1-sqrt10-sqrt2-cdots-sqrt10-sqrt99)

Comment: @jjagmath tried staring at small numbers, figuring out a way to telescope, subtracting the denominator and squaring, multiplying and dividing by the conjugate. None of that helped.

Comment: @RobertLee thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @jjagmath I know. But I don't see a reasonable way to do induction in this because the n inside the square root changes